# Nodejs ORM for MySQL UUID binary datatypes

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, binary, uuid

Are there any ORM for node.js that can support using binary as datatypes for storing UUID primary key in a MySQL databases? So far I have looked at Sequelize, waterline, loopback but all of them does not support this.

Answer (score 0):

Last I checked Sequelize does provide support for storing UUID primary keys for Mysql. I am using it in my projects.